# How to use question mark PreparedStatement (Java)?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want to create a java source object in oracle database via JDBC, `PreparedStatement`. However, in the java source file, there are several question marks. Once I executed it, I faced an error message like below..

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

I changed my code to be more understandable.

```
private void installOS_COMMAND() {
        Connection targetDBconn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            String SQL = "create or replace java source named \"FILE_TYPE_JAVA\" as\n"
                    + "public class FileType {\n"
                    + "    public static String getFileTypeOwner(Connection con) throws Exception {\n"
                    + "    String sFileTypeOwner = null;\n"
                    + "    CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall(\"begin dbms_utility.name_resolve(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); end;\");\n"
                    + "    stmt.setString(1, \"FILE_TYPE\");\n"
                    + "    stmt.setInt(2, 7);\n"
                    + "    stmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);\n"
                    + "    stmt.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);\n"
                    + "    stmt.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);\n"
                    + "    stmt.registerOutParameter(6, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);\n"
                    + "    stmt.registerOutParameter(7, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER);\n"
                    + "    stmt.registerOutParameter(8, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER);\n"
                    + "    stmt.execute();\n"
                    + "    sFileTypeOwner = stmt.getString(3);\n"
                    + "    stmt.close();\n"
                    + "    return sFileTypeOwner;\n"
                    + "  }\n"
                    + "}";
            targetDBconn = globalTargetConn.connect();
            pstmt = targetDBconn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException ex) { logWriter.writeLogs(logTextArea, LogWriter.ERROR, ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (pstmt != null ) try {pstmt.close();} catch(SQLException ex) {}
            if (targetDBconn != null ) try {targetDBconn.close();} catch(SQLException ex) {}
        }
    }
```

Is there someone who can fix this problem?

Comment: What is `SqlList.createFILE_TYPE_JAVA_javasourceSQL` ?

Comment: That is the one that I mentioned above the create or replace statement..

Comment: That query is nowhere to be found in the above code. Please include the absolute minimum required for us to understand the problem, and remove irrelevant stuff like your logging code.

Comment: If you are not using parameter substitution then consider just using a `Statement` instead of a `LoggableStatement` for this particular task.

Comment: I'm sorry but those are not really the entire java source code, I couldn't enter the entire code because it's too long. That SQL String is the little part of the entire code. Anyway, if I try to query the entire code which includes question marks, the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use prepared statements:

```
private void installOS_COMMAND() {
    Connection targetDBconn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        String SQL = "create or replace java source named \"FILE_TYPE_JAVA\" as\n"
                + "public class FileType {\n"
                + "    public static String getFileTypeOwner(Connection con) throws Exception {\n"
                + "    String sFileTypeOwner = null;\n"
                + "    CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall(\"begin dbms_utility.name_resolve(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); end;\");\n"
                + "    stmt.setString(1, \"FILE_TYPE\");\n"
                + "    stmt.setInt(2, 7);\n"
                + "    stmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);\n"
                + "    stmt.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);\n"
                + "    stmt.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);\n"
                + "    stmt.registerOutParameter(6, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);\n"
                + "    stmt.registerOutParameter(7, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER);\n"
                + "    stmt.registerOutParameter(8, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER);\n"
                + "    stmt.execute();\n"
                + "    sFileTypeOwner = stmt.getString(3);\n"
                + "    stmt.close();\n"
                + "    return sFileTypeOwner;\n"
                + "  }\n"
                + "}";
        targetDBconn = globalTargetConn.connect();
        stmt = targetDBconn.createStatement();
        stmt.setEscapeProcessing(false);
        stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
    } catch (SQLException ex) { logWriter.writeLogs(logTextArea, LogWriter.ERROR, ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (targetDBconn != null ) try {targetDBconn.close();} catch(SQLException ex) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not trying to enter  a row into the table. I'm just tying to instantly create a java source object in the oracle database using a preparedstatement.

Comment: ok, I don't know what that means. Anyway, the code you posted tries to evaluate the java-code in the SQL-string (including a non-java comment in the first line) as SQL, which will fail.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5013.htm  This link explains how to make a java source object into the database. And I meant that I'm trying to make that java source object directly  using jdbc(preparedstatement). sorry for my English :(

Comment: ah, you could either use a regular statement (not a prepared statement), or a prepared statement with the java-code as a parameter.

Comment: looking at some examples, it seems PreparedStatements probably doesn't work on CREATE JAVA. Thus, use just regular Statement.

Comment: Thanks Rolf, I edited your answer a little bit,  and it works now.